# change current activity in Sharepoint 2007 Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Is There any way to change current activity in Sharepoint 2007 Workflow ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of reading articles i found that this task doesn't supported by sequential workflow.